# Java Web Service SOAPFaultException error

Tags: java, web-services, soap, soa

My Java web service was working fine but suddenly somehow it throws error of below.

Please tell me what has happened? and what is the solution to resolve it?

```
javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAP11Fault.getProtocolException(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createException(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at $Proxy31.getGPRSConBillData(Unknown Source)
        at BillPostingService.postBill(BillPostingService.java:86)
        at ManualBillPostingService.postBill(ManualBillPostingService.java:27)
        at BatchBillPostingProcessor.postBill(BatchBillPostingProcessor.java:39)

        at BatchBillPostingProcessor.run(BatchBillPostingProcessor.java:31)
       CNO: 405000863 , Acknowledgement: E , Time millisec: -1347267052687
      javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAP11Fault.getProtocolException(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createException(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at $Proxy31.getGPRSConBillData(Unknown Source)
        at BillPostingService.postBill(BillPostingService.java:86)
        at ManualBillPostingService.postBill(ManualBillPostingService.java:27)
        at BatchBillPostingProcessor.postBill(BatchBillPostingProcessor.java:39)    
        at BatchBillPostingProcessor.run(BatchBillPostingProcessor.java:31)
        javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetExceptio
        nCNO: 405000570 , Acknowledgement: E , Time millisec: -1347267053187

        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAP11Fault.getProtocolException(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createException(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at $Proxy31.getGPRSConBillData(Unknown Source)
        at BillPostingService.postBill(BillPostingService.java:86)
        at ManualBillPostingService.postBill(ManualBillPostingService.java:27)
        at BatchBillPostingProcessor.postBill(BatchBillPostingProcessor.java:39)
```

Comment: can you show the source code?

Comment: ILLA - I have many java classes.. What do you want to see?

Comment: Add some detail information about your question like what web service you are using and the server details??

Comment: I am using Axis Web Service and that service is used by this url:         "https://203.77.203.196:8447/GetGPRSMtrBillService/services/GetGPRSConBillDataSoapPort"   where do you think is a problem??

Comment: Make sure your service is running in 8447 port. Before execute the code test your service in SOAPUI. It's really helps to check the web service alone

Comment: How can I get the wsdl( if I dont have the source code) and put it in SOAPUI to test?

Comment: The WSDL is here: https://203.77.203.196:8447/GetGPRSMtrBillService/services/GetGPRSConBillDataSoapPort?wsdl and just create new soap ui project using this WSDL url

Comment: Hey Thanks Paulius, I am new to Java. if that is the wsdl then the wsdl which I feed to SOAPUI is something different. What is that? Now, another questions is- My web service generates so much log so I have created shell script which deletes the log file every ten minutes.. Will it create any problem when web services is being used? Please advise.

Comment: My webservice was working well, but suddenly somehow it gives SOAPfault exceptions and sometimes unsupported media exceptions.. Is it due to the log file which i delete every 10 minutes?